# JS: ¿Cómo organizar y dividir contenido en varias páginas de pdf con contenedores anidados, manteniendo diseño y paginación coherentes?

Tags: javascript, pdf, dom, dompdf, nestjs

Estoy trabajando en nestJS para generar pdf desde el backend. Utilizo playwright para ejecutar chromium y generar el pdf y uso Handlebars para procesar los datos dinamicos. Y HTML y CSS para dibujar el contenido del pdf

Necesito poder generar las paginas y saltos del contenido de una pagina a otra de forma dinamica. De tal forma que se puedan crear contenedores anidados para organizar y dividir el contenido en varias paginas, asegurando que el diseño y la paginacion se realicen de manera controlada y coherente.

Encontre que manejando el DOM del HTML para generar el pdf puedo acceder a las clases para intentar controlar la forma en que se segmentara el contenido en cada pagina

**UPDATE 24/04/2024**

Ya logre crear la pagina y hacer el salto de contenido, este es el script actual

```
const alturaContenido = 738;
const contenidoDiv = document.getElementById("paginas");
const seccionesPrincipales = contenidoDiv.children;
let pageAccumulator = 0;
const alturaFooter = 110;

for (let i = 0; i < seccionesPrincipales.length; i++) {
    const seccionPrincipal = seccionesPrincipales[i];
    const seccionPrincipalHeight = seccionPrincipal.scrollHeight;

    console.log('seccionPrincipalHeight', seccionPrincipalHeight);
    console.log('pageAccumulator + seccionPrincipalHeight + alturaFooter', pageAccumulator + seccionPrincipalHeight + alturaFooter);
    // Verificar si la sección principal cabe en la página actual
    if (pageAccumulator + seccionPrincipalHeight + alturaFooter > alturaContenido) {
        console.log(`Nueva página para sección principal (${i + 1})`);
        // pageAccumulator = 0; // Restablecer el acumulador de página para la nueva página
        // Iterar sobre los elementos hijos de la sección principal
        const hijosDeSeccion = seccionPrincipal.children;
        console.log('hijosDeSeccion', hijosDeSeccion);
    
        for (let j = 0; j < hijosDeSeccion.length; j++) {
            const elementoHijo = hijosDeSeccion[j];
            const alturaElementoHijo = elementoHijo.scrollHeight || 0;

            console.log('alturaElementoHijo', alturaElementoHijo);
            console.log('pageAccumulator + alturaElementoHijo', pageAccumulator + alturaElementoHijo);

            // Verificar si el elemento hijo contribuye al desbordamiento
            if (pageAccumulator + alturaElementoHijo > alturaContenido) {
                const tableHijo = elementoHijo.querySelector('.tabledown');
            
                // Verificar si el desbordamiento se debe a un tbody
                if (tableHijo) {
                    console.log('Nuevo contenido en una página adicional');
                    const tbodyHeight = tableHijo.scrollHeight || 0;
                    console.log('tbodyHeight', tbodyHeight);
                    const addedContentHeight = alturaElementoHijo - tbodyHeight;
                    console.log('addedContentHeight', addedContentHeight);
                    pageAccumulator = addedContentHeight - alturaFooter;
                } else {
                    console.log(`Nueva página para elemento hijo (${i + 1}, ${j + 1})`);
                    pageAccumulator = 0;
                }
            } else {
                pageAccumulator += alturaElementoHijo; 
            }
        }
    } else {
        pageAccumulator += seccionPrincipalHeight
    }

}

console.log('Proceso completado');
```

El script hace varias cosas

- Define la altura del contenedor minima `const alturaContenido = 738;`
- Accede al contenedor del contenido `const contenidoDiv = document.getElementById("paginas");`
- Inicializo un contador `let pageAccumulator = 0;` que lleva la cuenta del espacio disponible en la página actual. Se utiliza para rastrear cuánto contenido cabe en la página antes de llegar al límite establecido `alturaContenido`.
- Itero sonre los hijos del `seccionesPrincipales` para evaluar si la altura de esos contenedor es mayor al que se establecio
- Luego iteramos sobre esos hijos para ver si dentro de ellos hay una tabla y ver como evaluar ese tamño
- Tambien se evalua la `alturaFooter` para poder tomar encuenta la altura de ese contenedor y que no ignore ese espacio cuando se despliegue el contenido

Pero el script sigue fallando, ya quecrea las paginas de acuerdo al contenido pero,

- El contenido aparece encima del footer

[image: ERROR CONTENIDO ENCIMA FOOTER]

- Y si hay una tabla en el HTML y no cabe en la pagina anterior la corta

[image: TABLA CORTADA DE UNA PAG A OTRA]

Ahora bien, si se preguntan porque valido si hay una tabla o no porque el contenido del HTML es dinamico a veces puede venir una tabla y otras veces no, es decir la traigo en mi JSON de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: pdf funcion]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
    <script src='/scripts/solicitud.js'></script>
    <style>
.contenedor {
  display: grid !important;
  grid-template-rows: 64px auto auto !important; /* Ajusta la altura máxima del contenido */
}

@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0; /* Restablecer los márgenes de impresión */
  }
  .contenedor {
    grid-template-rows: auto !important; /* Restablecer la altura máxima para la impresión */
  }
  /* Otros estilos de impresión que puedas necesitar */
}

  </style>
  </head>
  <body class='bg-white grid h-full' style='zoom: 1.2;'>

    <div id="tuFooterId" class='w-full'
      style="position: fixed !important; bottom: 0 !important">
      {{>footer}}
    </div>
    {{!-- Content --}}
    <section id="paginas" class="contenedor">
      {{> header}}
      <!-- Contenido de tu página -->
      <section class="px-6">
        <!-- Contenido normal -->
        <div class=' mt-2 flex flex-auto flex-col h-full gap-4'>
          {{! General }}
          <section class='inline-flex flex-col gap-2'>
            <div
              class='bg-patmed-black py-1.5 text-center text-[10px] font-bold uppercase text-white leading-[normal]'>
              {{servicio.nombre_servicio}}
              {{subcategoria.subcategoria_servicio}}
            </div>

            <div class='grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-1 px-2'>
              <div
                class='text-patmed-black font-bold text-[10px] mb-1  leading-[normal]'><span
                  class='text-patmed-pink-dark font-normal'>Paciente:</span>
                {{paciente.nombre_paciente}}
              </div>

              <div
                class='text-patmed-black font-bold text-[10px] mb-1 leading-[normal]'><span
                  class='text-patmed-pink-dark font-normal'>Médico
                  remitente:</span>
                {{#if medicosRemitentes.length}}{{#each
                medicosRemitentes}}{{this.nombre_cliente}}{{#unless
                @last
                }},{{/unless}}{{/each}}{{/if}}
              </div>

              <div class='flex flex-col gap-0'>
                <p class='text-patmed-gray-800 text-[8px] leading-[normal]'>
                  <b>Identidad:</b>
                  {{#if
                  paciente.numero_identidad}}{{paciente.numero_identidad}}{{/if}}
                </p>
                <p
                  class='text-patmed-gray-800 text-[8px] leading-[normal]'><b>Edad:</b>
                  {{paciente.edad}}
                  {{unidadTiempoEdad}}</p>
                <p
                  class='text-patmed-gray-800 text-[8px] leading-[normal]'><b>Género:</b>
                  {{paciente.genero}}</p>
              </div>

              <div class='flex flex-col'>
                <p
                  class='text-patmed-gray-800 text-[8px] leading-[normal]'><b>Material
                    estudiado:</b>
                  {{headerFormulario.material_enviado}}</p>
                <p
                  class='text-patmed-gray-800 text-[8px] leading-[normal]'><b>Sitio
                    de la toma:</b>
                  {{headerFormulario.sitio_de_la_toma}}</p>
                <p
                  class='text-patmed-gray-800 text-[8px] leading-[normal]'><b>Diagnóstico
                    clínico:</b>
                  {{headerFormulario.diagnostico_clinico}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>

          {{! Detail }}
          <section class='inline-flex flex-col gap-2'>
            <div
              class='bg-patmed-gray-100 text-patmed-black px-2 py-1.5 font-bold uppercase leading-[normal] text-[8px]'>
              Diagnóstico
            </div>
            <div class='px-2'>
              {{#if diagnostico}}
              <p
                class='mb-2 mr-3 text-patmed-gray-800 font-bold text-[10px] leading-2'>
                {{diagnostico.subtittle}}
              </p>
              <ul class='list-disc  list-inside ml-4'>
                {{#each diagnostico.item}}
                <li
                  class='text-patmed-gray-800 font-bold leading-2 text-[10px] !m-0'>{{this}}</li>
                {{/each}}
              </ul>
              <p
                class='mt-2 mr-3 text-patmed-gray-800 font-bold text-[10px] leading-2'>
                {{ifSpace diagnostico.comentario}}
              </p>
              {{/if}}
            </div>
          </section>

          <section class='specificSectionHeight flex flex-col gap-2'>
            <div
              class='bg-patmed-gray-100 text-patmed-black px-2 py-1.5 font-bold uppercase leading-[normal] text-[8px]'>
              Descripción Macroscópica</div>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
              nulla minima velit, exercitationem, provident saepe fugiat
              voluptates fuga eaque, laborum eius? Atque praesentium fuga
              veritatis rerum illo doloribus deleniti odit.</p>

            <table class="tabledown w-full text-[8px]">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td
                    style="text-align: center; font-size:10px; background-color:#D3D3D3;"
                    colspan="4">
                    <b>Punteo Allred</b>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="4">
                    <b>Punteo Allred</b>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">Punteo de proporción de
                    positividad</td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">Porcentaje de células
                    positivas</td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">Punteo de intensidad</td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">Intensidad de la
                    positividad</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">Ninguna</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="4">
                    <b>Control Positivo</b>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="4">
                    <b>Total (Punteo de proporción de positividad + punteo de
                      intensidad) = 0</b>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="4">Punteo de 0-2 puntos, se interpreta como
                    negativo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="4">
                    <b>RP (Rececptor de Progesterona)</b>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">Punteo de proporción de
                    positividad</td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">Porcentaje de células
                    positivas</td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">Punteo de intensidad</td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">Intensidad de la
                    positividad</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">3</td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">30%</td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">2</td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">Fuerte</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

            <div
              class='bg-patmed-gray-100 text-patmed-black px-2 py-1.5 font-bold uppercase leading-[normal] text-[8px] my-2'>
              Descripción Macroscópica
            </div>

            <p
              class='text-patmed-gray-800 leading-2 text-[10px] my-2 px-2 mb-4'
              style='font-weight: 400 !important;'>
              {{descripcionMacro.jsonData.content}}
            </p>

            <div class='grid grid-cols-3 gap-2'>
              {{#each fotoMacro}}
              <div class='flex flex-col gap-1 '>
                <div style=" width:180px; height: 128px;">
                  <img src='{{this.url_o_base64}}' style="object-fit: cover;"
                    alt='Imagen' />
                </div>
                <p class='leading-2 text-[10px] mt-1'
                  style="max-width: 180px;">{{this.content}}</p>
              </div>
              {{/each}}

            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </section>

      {{!-- <section style='display:grid; grid-template-rows: 802px auto;'>

        <section class="specific-section px-6 pt-6 flex flex-col"
          style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
          <div style="flex: 1;">
            <div
              class='bg-patmed-black py-1.5 text-center text-[10px] font-bold uppercase text-white leading-[normal]'>
              {{servicio.nombre_servicio}}
              {{subcategoria.subcategoria_servicio}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

      </section> --}}
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Gracias de antemano por cualquier tipo de ayuda que me brinden. Saludos.

Comment: Si es que entendí bien lo que estas haciendo, debes usar CSS para generar las páginas ver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page esto funciona bien para casos básicos, para cosas más complejas el estándar está atrasado por lo que debes usar polyfill como este https://pagedjs.org/documentation/

Comment: Sii, es practicamente eso, si el tamaño del contenedor secundario es mayor al tamaño del contenedor principal entonces creamos una nueva pagina y validamos el contenido que hara el salto. Lo estaba intentando con el DOM porque es lo mas directo, intente usar pagedjs (no conocia la lib) me gusto, pero no le entendi muy bien entonces trabaje en el script con JS siempre usando el DOM e hice unos cambios, ahorita actualizare mi pregunta

Comment: segun la ultima edicion, entonces no se estan respetando los margenes ni el espacio del footer ...

Comment: has intentado algo como esto: `if (pageAccumulator + seccionPrincipalHeight + alturaFooter > alturaContenido) ....`

Comment: que dice la documentacion sobre el desbordamiento de tablas?

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por sus recomendaciones. Al final solucione usando la opcion footerTemplate de la libreria playwright y realice una funcion como la que mostre aqui para validar el tamaño del contenido. Aunque con solo la libreria realice todo el trabajo